# What is the jargon for REST messages (ie request body and response body)

Tags: rest, terminology

I know this probably a dumb question but I know that the REST urls one hits in REST parlance are called "*resources*".

My question is what should one call the response/request bodies. Should they be called states?

Media Types can't be right because that is the format (ie XML, or JSON). Maybe "State"?

For now I have been using the term "message".

Comment: I know some people are voting to close this message. Please add a comment why so that I can fix it. Programming is more than just about making the computer do what you want: its also about communicating to future viewers of your code through proper terminology. So I know its not a: this code is not working question but I still think its fit for this site particularly since other naming questions have been asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct term is "representations". They are snapshots in time of the actual resource referred to by the URI.

REST stands for "Representational State Transfer", so the answer is right in the name. REST is about the transmission of representations around a system in such a way that work can be done on the real resource on the server side. The encoding of the representation is dictated by the Media Type used for content negotiation.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that also hence why I was guessing at "state". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think "resource" is the proper term for the request/response body.  The URIs are the identifiers of those resources.

Have a look at this blog entry: http://blog.dhananjaynene.com/2009/06/why-rest/.  This is one of the best explanations of REST that I have seen.  In it, the author explicitly states that these entities are typically called resources.

Comment: Fielding makes it pretty clear in his thesis that the resource is a conceptual thing (to which a URI refers). People use "resource" as a synecdoche for all kinds of pieces of the conversation of course, but it is not itself an artifact.